# how I can mapping complex JSON to other JSON

Tags: go

I am trying to build *aggregation services*, to all third party APIs that's I used,
this *aggregation services* taking json values coming from my main system and it will put this value to key equivalent to third party api key then, *aggregation services* it will send request to third party api with new json format.

example-1:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/tidwall/gjson"
)

func main() {
    // mapping JSON
    mapB := []byte(`
    {
        "date": "createdAt",
        "clientName": "data.user.name"
    }
    `)

    // from my main system
    dataB := []byte(`
    {
        "createdAt": "2017-05-17T08:52:36.024Z",
        "data": {
            "user": {
                "name": "xxx"
            }
        }
    }
    `)

    mapJSON := make(map[string]interface{})
    dataJSON := make(map[string]interface{})
    newJSON := make(map[string]interface{})

    err := json.Unmarshal(mapB, &mapJSON)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(dataB, &dataJSON)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    for i := range mapJSON {
        r := gjson.GetBytes(dataB, mapJSON[i].(string))
        newJSON[i] = r.Value()
    }

    newB, err := json.MarshalIndent(newJSON, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(newB))
}
```

output:

```
{
  "clientName": "xxx",
  "date": "2017-05-17T08:52:36.024Z"
}
```

I use [gjson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson) package to get values form my main system request in simple way from a json document.

example-2:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/tidwall/gjson"
)

func main() {
    // mapping JSON
    mapB := []byte(`
    {
        "date": "createdAt",
        "clientName": "data.user.name",
        "server":{
            "google":{
                "date" :"createdAt"
            }
        }
    }
    `)

    // from my main system
    dataB := []byte(`
    {
        "createdAt": "2017-05-17T08:52:36.024Z",
        "data": {
            "user": {
                "name": "xxx"
            }
        }
    }
    `)

    mapJSON := make(map[string]interface{})
    dataJSON := make(map[string]interface{})
    newJSON := make(map[string]interface{})

    err := json.Unmarshal(mapB, &mapJSON)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(dataB, &dataJSON)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    for i := range mapJSON {
        r := gjson.GetBytes(dataB, mapJSON[i].(string))
        newJSON[i] = r.Value()
    }

    newB, err := json.MarshalIndent(newJSON, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(newB))
}
```

output:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not string
```

*I can handle this error by using  https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions, but what if this json object have array and inside this array have json object ....*

**my problem is I have different apis, every api have own json schema, *and my way for mapping json only work if
third party api have json key value only, without nested json or array inside this array json object.***

is there a way to mapping complex json schema, or golang package to help me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After comment interaction and with updated question. Before we move forward, I would like to mention.

> I just looked at your `example-2` Remember one thing. Mapping is from one form to another form. Basically `one known format to targeted format`. Each data type have to handled. You cannot do `generic` to `generic` mapping logically (technically feasible though, would take more time & efforts, you can play around on this).

I have created sample working program of one approach; it does a mapping of source to targeted format. Refer this program as a start point and use your creativity to implement yours.

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/MEk_nGcPjZ

**Explanation:** Sample program achieves two different source format to one target format. The program consist of -

- Targeted Mapping definition of Provider 1
- Targeted Mapping definition of Provider 2
- Provider 1 JSON
- Provider 2 JSON
- Mapping function
- Targeted JSON marshal

**Key elements from program:** refer play link for complete program.

```
type MappingInfo struct {
    TargetKey     string
    SourceKeyPath string
    DataType      string
}
```

**Map function:**

```
func mapIt(mapping []*MappingInfo, parsedResult gjson.Result) map[string]interface{} {
    mappedData := make(map[string]interface{})
    for _, m := range mapping {
        switch m.DataType {
        case "time":
            mappedData[m.TargetKey] = parsedResult.Get(m.SourceKeyPath).Time()
        case "string":
            mappedData[m.TargetKey] = parsedResult.Get(m.SourceKeyPath).String()
        }
    }
    return mappedData
}
```

**Output:**

```
Provider 1 Result: map[date:2017-05-17 08:52:36.024 +0000 UTC clientName:provider1 username]
Provider 1 JSON: {
  "clientName": "provider1 username",
  "date": "2017-05-17T08:52:36.024Z"
}

Provider 2 Result: map[date:2017-05-12 06:32:46.014 +0000 UTC clientName:provider2 username]
Provider 2 JSON: {
  "clientName": "provider2 username",
  "date": "2017-05-12T06:32:46.014Z"
}
```

Good luck, happy coding!

---

Typically Converting/Transforming one structure to another structure, you will have to handle this with application logic.

As you mentioned in the question:

> my problem is I have different apis, every api have own json schema

This is true for every `aggregation` system.

---

One approach to handle this requirement effectively; is to keep mapping of keys for each provider JSON structure and targeted JSON structure.

**For example:** This is an approach, please go with your design as you see fit.

**JSON structures from various provider:**

```
// Provider 1 : JSON structrure
{
  "createdAt": "2017-05-17T08:52:36.024Z",
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "name": "xxx"
    }
  }
}

// Provider 2 : JSON structrure
{
  "username": "yyy"
  "since": "2017-05-17T08:52:36.024Z",
}
```

**Mapping for target JSON structure:**

```
jsonMappingByProvider := make(map[string]string)

// Targeted Mapping for Provider 1
jsonMappingByProvider["provider1"] = `
{
    "date": "createdAt",
    "clientName": "data.user.name"
}
`

// Targeted Mapping for Provider 2
jsonMappingByProvider["provider2"] = `
{
    "date": "since",
    "clientName": "username"
}
`
```

Now, based the on the provider you're handling, get the mapping and map the response JSON into targeted structure.

```
// get the mapping info by provider
mapping := jsonMappingByProvider["provider1"]

// Parse the response JSON 
// Do the mapping
```

This way you can control each provider and it's mapping effectively.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but my problem is **mapping**, as you know golang strongly typed, because that many problems happen to me, I'm trying to find a solution for this or golang package to help me to mapping json.

Comment: Thanks, can you please describe your issues you faced with mapping? So that I can provide my inputs.

Comment: I have updated the answer, have a look. I believe it gives you an idea to start then you can accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for your times.